# Photoresistor in Parallel

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I am currently building a photoresistor from a kit that I bought a few months ago. I had a few questions when I was building this circuit:

1. What happens when you wire the photoresistor in parallel with the LED-resistor combo instead of in series with the LED-resistor combo? I believe it gets dimmer but I am not exactly sure why this is.
2. What happens when you wire the photoresistor in parallel with the LED but have the LED + photoresistor in series with the other resistor?

Comment: Please share the schematic of the circuit you're building. Without it it's hard to be sure we're giving you helpful answers.